# How do i find the min\max value Numpy array

Tags: python, image, function, numpy

I am trying to get the non-white min and max pixel location for this image along the axis = 0.  However, np.where isn't working along axis = zero.  I have ried other np function and they do not work. I have read the documentation and still no resolve. Does anyone have a function for this?
[image]

[image]

Comment: What is `w.shape`?

Comment: This is the shape [236, 213, 3]

Comment: Read what [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) does again. Taking the `max` of what it returns is giving you the largest non-white index, not the index of the largest non-white value

Comment: AJ I read the documentation. And clearly this is working in axis = 1.   Do you know of another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, the goal is to find indices of rows and columns bounding the area of the image that contains all non-white pixels. This can be done, for example, as follows.

Load a sample image:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = plt.imread("sample.jpg").copy()
plt.imshow(img)
```

[image: sample image]

Find the bounding box of non-white pixels and display the result:

```
# indices of non-white pixels 
rows, cols = np.nonzero(np.any(img != 255, axis=-1))
# indices of rows and columns of the bounding box
rbox = rows.min(), rows.max()
cbox = cols.min(), cols.max()

# show the selection
img[rbox[0]:rbox[1]+1, cbox[0]:cbox[1]+1, 1] = 0
plt.imshow(img)
```

[image: image with the bounding box]

Comment: Thanks  it worked.   your help was greatly appreciated.  do u have a cash app?

Comment: @TammaraBrown No cash app, I am glad it was helpful.

Comment: i have another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70661012/save-image-with-bounding-box ..